# submit with Jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, submit

I'm using the Jquery autocomplete [INFO](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

I'm trying to submit the text of the list item when clicked on. So I tried:

```
select: function(e, ui){
        $('form').submit();

       }
```

What it does now is submitting the val of input and not the list item text. How can I submit the list item instead?

Comment: What do you mean by _"list item text"_?

Comment: Where is your list item?

Comment: @gdoron The data in the drop down list

Comment: Check the properties of `ui`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly what you're trying to submit, but you can make a hidden field, and in your event put the "list" in your hidden field. In this case when your form is submitted you can get the value of your hidden field.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out and thats what Im doing right now. But it seems like a workaround. I would prefer doing the submit as an event inside the autocomplete. I think this is better.

Comment: you can do it in select, something like:
select: function(e, ui){
$(yourHidden).val(yourList);
        $('form').submit();

       }

Answer (score 0):

So I did submit(on enter key) on close like this:

```
close: function(e, ui){
        $('form').submit();
       }
```

And I took care of the mouse click like this:

```
$('.ui-autocomplete').click(function() {
$('form').submit();
});
```

Could this 'workaround' cause problems?? Are there specific situations in which this wouldn't work...??

(If I don't hear anything I'm accepting my own answer(: )

Comment: I just noticed the problem with this....If I click anywhere else in the body, the form is submitted because the autocomplete will close....So this doesn't work )-: Any help would be appreciated